# Angularjs connection to kaazing

Tags: angularjs, websocket, kaazing

Can anybody share some sample code where 'angular javascript' module interacts over web sockets with 'kaazing' JMS. I have created a small application SPA which is using ember right now but now i want to get it converted to angular. I tried to find something on internet but as such not much available in terms on angular and kaazing together.

Comment: Bee - we have a sample that one of our lead engineers will make available soon.

Comment: @PeterMoskovits thats wonderful...However, any timeline when it would be available publicly for customization.

Comment: We're shooting for end of this week (Oct 5, 2014).

Answer (score 0):

I posted the sample on [github](https://github.com/pmoskovi/KaazingAngular). Let me know if you have any questions.